# How to get middle word out of 3 word vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have one vector which contain trigram .
i want middle word out of them .
What is the method or regular expression for that ?
Example :
i have one vector z which has data like

```
[1] "adn afn grdsg"
[2] "sfnds enfsi sekj"
[3] "ajsf aser afgbt"
.
.
.
```

and my resuling answer i vector of following

```
[1] "afn" "enfsi" "aser" 
[4] ....
```

like this .

Answer (score 2):

If you want a baseR solution, you can first split the string by space, to give a list, then collapse that list back to a vector and select the second element:

```
> unlist(strsplit(x, " "))[2]
[1] "afn"
```

**Data:**

```
x <- "adn afn grdsg"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(str1, 2)
#[1] "afn"   "enfsi" "aser"
```

Or with `str_extract`

```
str_extract(str1, "(?<=\\s)\\w+(?=\\s)")
#[1] "afn"   "enfsi" "aser"
```

---

Or another option is `sub` to match the second set of non-whitespaces characters, capture as a string and use the backreference (`\\1`) in the replacement.

```
sub("\\S+\\s+(\\S+)\\s+.*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "afn"   "enfsi" "aser"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c( "adn afn grdsg",  "sfnds enfsi sekj", "ajsf aser afgbt")
```

Comment: Can also be more generalized `word(str1, str_count(str1, '\\w+')%/%2+1)`

Comment: @Sotos That is a great addition.  You could post that as a new solution as none of the solutions here addressed it properly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers already posted, we can generalize it with,

```
library(stringr)
word(x, str_count(x, '\\w+')%/%2+1)
#[1] "grdsg" "enfsi"
```

where,

```
x <- c('adn afn grdsg fdgdg dghd', "sfnds enfsi sekj")
```